# Why does MVC validation not work for "<" and ">"?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I have this MVC application, and I want to be able to allow a user to be able to enter a username that is 6 to 255 characters long, including special characters that I deem fit. I have a simple regex for this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9!\@#\$%\^&\(\)-_\+\.'`~/=\?\{\}\|]){6,255}$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AdminResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserNameFormatError")]
```

The validation works to a certain extent. It will not let you enter in a username shorter than 6 characters, and it will not let you enter one longer than 255, and it will also let you use all of the special characters I have listed. Interestingly though, it will also let you use "<" and ">", which I don't want to let it use, because then you start getting some errors on the backend because security stuff thinks you are trying to inject malicious code or w/e. That's beside the point, how come the validation allows use of those when they are not included in the regex?

Comment: I suspect the dash may be the culprit. Except at the beginning of the group, doesn't it denote a range? So you are allowing everything between `)` and `_`? Maybe?

Comment: i think you may be right! I forgot to escape the dash. Will test and post a comment to let you know

Comment: You were right. I would have never noticed that! Been staring at it for hours and trying different things. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3):

The dash seems to be the culprit. Except at the beginning of the group, it would denote a range. So you are allowing everything between `)` and `_`. You can escape or move it.